# Adding attributes to XML based on consecutive occurance of a particular element in source XML through XSLT

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

I am working on the XSLT.

```
Depending upon the values in the table I have to write the  XML file.
```

Rules:

```
1.If the values in columns of I row are in strong(Enclosed in<strong> tags).
  Then I have to add attribute as "FirstRowIsStrong".

2.If all the values in the I column are in strong. 
   Then I have to add attribute as "FirstCoulmnIsStrong".

3.If the values in any row are in Strong, 
    then I have to add attribute as  "RowIsStrong". 
    If its the first row I need not add attribute.
    If the values in First row are in strong I should not add attribute.
    For the rows other than First row, I have to add the attribute.
```

I have source XML like this.

```
        <table style="WIDTH: 100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">

        <tr>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">A</strong></td>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">B</strong></td>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">C</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">D</strong></td>
        <td>E</td>
        <td>F</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">G</strong></td>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">H</strong></td>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">I</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
        <td><strong xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">J</strong></td>
        <td>K</td>
        <td>L</td>
        </tr>

        </table>
```

I should have the output as

```
<tabledata FirstRowIsStrong="true" FirstCoulmnIsStrong="true">
    <row>
        <column>A</column>
        <column>B</column>
        <column>C</column>          
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>D</column>
        <column>E</column>
        <column>F</column>          
    </row>
    <row RowIsStrong="true">
        <column>G</column>
        <column>H</column>
        <column>I</column>          
    </row>
    <row>
        <column>J</column>
        <column>K</column>
        <column>L</column>          
    </row>
  </tabledata>
```

I could able to get the values, but I am not sure how to add the attributes as per the requirement.

Can any one help me out how it can be done.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the **FirstRowIsStrong** you need a test to check there the first row does not contain a **td** element which has no **strong** element

```
<xsl:if test="tr[1][not(td[not(xhtml:strong)])]">
```

Similary, for the **FirstColumnIsStrong** you need a test to check there is no row first a first cell that does not contain a **strong** element

```
<xsl:if test="not(tr[td[1][not(xhtml:strong)]])">
```

And for the **RowIsStrong** you can use a template match to check the non-first row does not contain any such **td** elements

```
<xsl:template match="tr[position() != 1][not(td[not(xhtml:strong)])]">
```

Here is the full XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:template match="table">
      <tabledata>
         <xsl:if test="tr[1][not(td[not(xhtml:strong)])]">
            <xsl:attribute name="FirstRowIsStrong">true</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:if test="not(tr[td[1][not(xhtml:strong)]])">
            <xsl:attribute name="FirstColumnIsStrong">true</xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </tabledata>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tr[position() != 1][not(td[not(xhtml:strong)])]">
      <row RowIsStrong="true">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </row>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="tr">
      <row>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </row>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="td">
      <column>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </column>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="xhtml:strong">
      <strong>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </strong>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your input XML, the following is output

```
<tabledata FirstRowIsStrong="true" FirstColumnIsStrong="true" style="WIDTH: 100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
   <row>
      <column>
         <strong>A</strong>
      </column>
      <column>
         <strong>B</strong>
      </column>
      <column>
         <strong>C</strong>
      </column>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column>
         <strong>D</strong>
      </column>
      <column>E</column>
      <column>F</column>
   </row>
   <row RowIsStrong="true">
      <column>
         <strong>G</strong>
      </column>
      <column>
         <strong>H</strong>
      </column>
      <column>
         <strong>I</strong>
      </column>
   </row>
   <row>
      <column>
         <strong>J</strong>
      </column>
      <column>K</column>
      <column>L</column>
   </row>
</tabledata>
```

Do note the extra code to remove the namespace from the **strong** element